# MYSQL error 1292 Incorrext datetime value while insert into table

Tags: mysql, datetime, insert, mysql-error-1292

For a personnal reason, I need to create a table from a view. So I create my table like this

```
drop table if exists  ef_vues_venues_clients;
CREATE TABLE ef_vues_venues_clients (
    client_id integer primary key,
    annee_saison integer,
    semaine integer,
    periode char(2),
    saison varchar(10),
    date_venue date,
    station varchar(10)
);
```

And then I want to insert my values like this :

```
insert into ef_vues_venues_clients(
    client_id,
    annee_saison,
    semaine,
    periode,
    saison, 
    date_venue,station) 

    select client_id, 
        annee_saison,
        semaine,
        periode,
        saison, 
        if(date_venue='',NULL,str_to_date(date_venue,'%Y-%m-%d')),
        station 
    from ef_venues_clients;
```

But I have this error :

```
Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '13'
```

To be sure that it doesn't come from my data, i try to insert just one line like this :

```
   insert into ef_vues_venues_clients(
    client_id,
    annee_saison,
    semaine,
    periode,
    saison, 
    date_venue,station) 

    select client_id, 
        annee_saison,
        semaine,
        periode,
        saison, 
        if(date_venue='',NULL,str_to_date(date_venue,'%Y-%m-%d')),
        station 
    from ef_venues_clients
   order by date_venue desc LIMIT 1;
```

But the same error.

The result of the select is this :

```
client_id, annee_saison, semaine, periode, saison, str_to_date(date_venue,'%Y-%m-%d'), station
333             2020        NULL    p1      hiver   2020-02-18                      StationName
```

There isn't any '13' here, so I don't understand...

Can you help me please ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Execute 
```CREATE TABLE tmp_table
SELECT client_id, annee_saison, semaine, periode, saison, date_venue, station FROM ef_venues_clients;```. Then show DDL of created table and its data (a lot of rows), and look for `date_venue` values which does not match the pattern `'%Y-%m-%d'` (`WHERE date_venue NOT REGEXP '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'`).

Comment: @Akina I have already gone through all the data in my views and have only fair or null dates. Also, normally since I set a Limit to only display the first row, it should work fine since this row is correct, right?

Comment: 1) Please execute my query and show DDL. At least show the definition of `date_venue` column. 2) Show `SELECT date_venue, HEX(date_venue) FROM tmp_table` for 1-2 rows which fails on `str_to_date(date_venue,'%Y-%m-%d')` expression.

Comment: DDL : is it this ? 
`CREATE TABLE ef_vues_venues_clients (
  client_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  annee_saison int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 semaine int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  periode char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  saison varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  date_venue date DEFAULT NULL,
  station varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`client_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`

And the result of two date_venue which fails :`2020-02-18 323032302D30322D3138
2020-02-18 323032302D30322D3138`

Comment: *DDL : is it this ?* NO. I have asked the same for a table which will be created after executing the query which I have provided above. *the result of two date_venue which fails* - they're absolutely correct, so the problem source is somewhere else.

Comment: If everything else seems correct check for triggers and what they are doing.

Comment: @Akina I don't have any table created because I need to create a table,and insert all the line comes from a view (ef_venues_clients). I'm so sorry that I didn't understand everything you ask me, especially since you spend time helping me, but English is not my native langage

Comment: @P.Salmon Thank you for your answer. I don't have any triggers or procedures for the moment

Comment: The first sentence of my first comment contains the query. Do you see it? While executing this query creates a table `tmp_table` and saves the data into it. Have you executed the query? Does the table was created? If true for all 3 questions - execute `SHOW CREATE TABLE tmp_table;` and provide its output.

Comment: Is ef_venues_clients your VIEW (as in create view) if so show the code and sample data from the tables it selects from.

Comment: Thank you @Akina. Your code made the same error, 'Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '13''. So the table was not created. Your query is exatly what i've tried first, and since it didn't work I tried breaking down the steps before posting here

Comment: @P.Salmon I don't know if I have the right to show my code because it itself uses confidential views to be created. But here is an excerpt from the base table, through which I created my view:
`CREATE TABLE my table (
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  client_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
date_valid datetime DEFAULT NULL,
...
...
PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY IDX_134EA17919EB6921 (client_id),
CONSTRAINT FK_134EA17919EB6921 FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES ef_client (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;`

Comment: It's a time to show your view code and source tables structures.

Comment: You don't have to show confidential data made up data which illustrates your problem is fine.

Comment: And here is the final view `CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=root@localhost SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW ef_count_client_station_venues AS select ef_venues_clients.client_id AS client_id,ef_venues_clients.station AS station,count(ef_venues_clients.annee_saison) AS nombre_venues from ef_venues_clients group by ef_venues_clients.client_id,ef_venues_clients.station;`

Answer (score 0):

As its name indicates datetime expects "%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s" format.
So can you try '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'

Comment: But my column is just a date, not a datetime. By the way, i try this and same error

insert into ef_vues_venues_clients(client_id, annee_saison,semaine,periode,saison, date_venue,station) select client_id, annee_saison,semaine,periode,saison, str_to_date(date_venue,'%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'),station from ef_venues_clients order by date_venue desc LIMIT 1;

Comment: @MangueSutcliff *But my column is just a date, not a datetime.* This is safe - the value will be converted before storing (maybe with the warning that the value was truncated).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your date_venue variable is already of type DATE. The INSERT statement seems to work properly. str_to_date tries to convert a DATE variable but expects a VARCHAR variable. I would try to leave out the str_to_date function:

```
 if(date_venue='',NULL,date_venue),
```

Comment: I did that :
`insert into ef_vues_venues_clients(client_id, annee_saison,semaine,periode,saison, date_venue,station) select client_id, annee_saison,semaine,periode,saison,  if(date_venue='',NULL,date_venue),station from ef_venues_clients LIMIT 1;
` and same error..

Comment: *str_to_date tries to convert a DATE variable but expects a VARCHAR variable.* This is safe - MySQL have soft datatype, and DATE value will be converted to string datatype before the function call.